# simple .htaccess rewrite URL to different directory on same server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I'm clueless here...

I need to rewrite a directory structure and all sub-directories within it to a directory within the same server, but a root that is before the directory.

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Themes/default/css/folder
```

and all directories called upon after folder.  Such as `folder/sub_folder` or `folder/afolder/anotherfolder`, it needs to include **ALL** sub-directories within the `folder` directory.

should be redirected to this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com
```

How do I do this via a .htaccess file within the `folder` path `http://www.mydomain.com/Themes/default/css/folder`?

Please someone help.

Thanks guys :)

The files within the directory structure still need to be accessible for that structure when called via PHP, but I don't want people being able to browse to `http://www.mydomain.com/Themes/default/css/folder` and be shown all subdirectories within that folderpath and/or all files.  Same thing for all sub-directories that follow that folder path.

I'd like to be able to place the .htaccess file within the `http://www.mydomain.com/Themes/default/css/folder` directory on the server, but don't know exactly what code to use for this.

ALSO, even more challenging...  The domain name can change, so I'd rather not use the domain name within the .htaccess file, instead perhaps use .. or . to go up a directory or a different method of grabbing the domain name within the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in `/Themes/default/css/folder` and place these lines there (**it requires mod_rewrite**):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) all requests to a **folder** to a homepage. If file is requested, it will allow it.

If you want to have it working for folders as well as files then remove the `RewriteCond` line -- it will redirect **ALL requests** (even for non-existing URLs) to a homepage.

If you will see *"500 Internal Server Error"* after creating such file, **then it is your server configuration**: mod_rewrite may not be enabled or it's directives (RewriteRule, RewriteCond, RewriteEngine) are not allowed to be placed in .htaccess. In any case -- check Apache's error log for exact error message (it will give you the exact reason).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/prevent-directory-listing.html

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: adding in `Options –Indexes` totally took my whole site down with a 500 error bro!  Besides I just want to REDIRECT to the domain name when a condition exists within the URL.  And when I added the .htaccess file to the folder, all files within any directories are NOW inaccessible!

Comment: If you contue reading you'll find out tha you can do something like `IndexIgnore *.png` to ignore png's in this case, and thus able to make a list of files not to be listed.

Comment: I don't want any files/folders listed.  I only want to be able to access them via PHP or within the internal script files.  How to do this?

Comment: This does not help me any.  It is still showing the subdirectories within the folder when browsing to the url path of the folder.

Comment: You'll have to do a .htaccess for each case, no workaround :)

Comment: To block any file / folder listing within a directory : `IndexIgnore *`

Comment: You can, however, create a server-side script to automatically generate a .htaccess file for each folder you need to, that would probably be best once you know you have what you need.

Comment: @ yoda - LazyOne answered my question.  I knew this was possible bro!  Thanks anyways!